# Is it possible to get access to installed apps shared data in android?

Tags: java, android, aidl

Health Mobile applications have rich data of their user physical condition and normally store it in their cloud databases. 
I wonder if there is an app which got data from their users in a local database and shares it with other apps that are installed in user phone(Something like `Android Interface Definition Language` for example)?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.it's not that simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> using other health tracker apps data

Step #0: Hire qualified legal counsel and discuss your plans regarding taking health information from other apps. Please note that this subject area (personal health data) usually has a lot of regulation around it, and you may be subject to civil or criminal penalties if you are not careful.

Step #1: Come up with a list of "other health tracker apps".

Step #2: Contact the developers of those apps and see if they have any sort of API for allowing third parties access to those apps' data. Due to the aforementioned legal issues, I expect that few will say yes, but there may be a few who do.

Step #3: Create your app, using those health apps' APIs. The details for doing that would depend upon those specific apps and their specific APIs.

Comment: OMG! you mean there's no  straightforward way and free api for it?

Comment: @MarziehHeidari: There is no "straightforward and free api" for developers to access private data out of other apps, for obvious privacy and security reasons.